# What difference the recursive call of two functions, having different number of arrays passed as arguments, will have on system stack

Tags: c++, recursion, stack, system

I have two arrays (a[] and b[]) of the same type,size  (their size can be very large) and having same elements values.
Now using these arrays I can call one of these two function recursively, whose definition are

```
void function_1(int *a);  
void function_2(int *a,int *b);
```

I want to know what difference, the recursive calls of these functions, will have on the system stack i.e. will they both need same space or if the second function needs more space, what is the amount of difference created by recursively calling these functions.

Comment: `function_1` passes 1 pointer on the stack; `function_2` passes 2 pointers on the stack.  That's all.  Size of a pointer is implementation defined typically 4 or 8 bytes (32 bit or 64 bit application).

Comment: `function_2()` will need double the stack size than `function_1()`.

Comment: The parameters are pointers, not arrays.

Comment: The `function_2` may also use more local variables.  Local variables contribute to the stack space.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to know what difference, the recursive calls of these functions, will have on the system stack

`function_2` will use twice as much stack space for the parameters as `function_1` does. This is because it has twice as many arguments (of the same size).

Comment: Both stack frames will have a return pointer as well so that makes `function_2` using  50% more space than `function_1` (3 machine pointers instead of 2)

Comment: @Sylwester they may use stack space for internal state of the function as well.

Comment: What internal state?

Comment: @Sylwester automatic variables.